# CIFaceFeature hasFaceAngle property not working

Tags: ios, core-image, face-recognition

I'm implementing face detection in iOS, so far so good, I get the CIFaceFeature returning properties like bounds, right eye, left eye, mouth positions.

However, the face never seems to return `float faceAngle` or `BOOL hasFaceAngle`.

There doesn't seem to be any particular CIDetector option required to activate it (unless I'm wrong). Any help or suggestions appreciated. Thank you.